# using google maps in webview

Tags: android, dictionary, webview

I'm trying to display google map in a webview but the problem is when I try to open it its open in google maps app or any other browser on the phone.

*So how can I open it in just the webview?*

**My Code :**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" 
            + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" 
            + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

before

```
webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" 
            + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" 
            + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
```

Comment: sorry my url is missing that im searching for hospital will that be possible in your code

Comment: actually adding the above code prevents opening the map in maps app or browser, and instead loads the map inside webview.

Comment: http://www.ciiycode.com/06H6zWqQqjxx/search-nearby-hospital-via-google-map-intent-android

Comment: try the above link,hope it helps you. Another option will be to integrate Google Maps API

Comment: ok when i tried  with it it opens in the google app i want it to open in the webview

Comment: ok how to open google maps in my app and show only hospitals if possible